# how to return a stream list from a for loop in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

The code and comments kind of explains it better than I can articulate it.
basically I want to return a Stream of something but only based on certain parameters. Those parameters are coming from an array.

here is an example.

say we have an array with values ["1", "2", "3"]

and in the database I have a docids of ["1", "2","3","4"]

I want a stream that will return everything but that four, or to better articulate it. I want a stream list that will return only the items that have the docid of the array with those values specified aka [1,2,3]

what I did below was loop through the example array so the first item "c" will be "1".

it will take this "1" and use a where to see if a docid matches this "1". I need to store this somehow and then return it once it is "fullly" populated. or populated at all since it is a stream. The example array of [1,2,3] could change in the future to maybe [1,2,3,4] so when that happens I would like the data to be pulled from the database.

```
     class UserData {
  String uid;
  String firstName;
  int rating;
  List<String> classes;  //need to be able to access this

  UserData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    firstName = data['firstname'] ?? "";
    rating = data['rating'] ?? "";
    classes = data['classes'].cast<String>() ?? "";
  }

  

  Stream<List<ClassData>> getTheUserClasses = (() async* {
    List<ClassData> d = List<ClassData>();

    for (String c in classes) { //no longer able to access classes
      // this will store the data of the matched value
      var _matchData = Firestore.instance
          .collection("Classes")
          .where('classid', isEqualTo: c)
          .snapshots()
          .map((event) => event.documents
              .map((e) => ClassData.fromUserMap(e.data, e.documentID)));

      // and when you have it, append
      d.add(_matchData); //error here from type differences
    }

    // after the loop you can test your response then yield
    d.forEach((item) => print(item));

    // return the data which is required
    yield d;
  })();

  UserData({this.firstName, this.rating, this.classes});
}
```

[image]

Here is a way I have already done this. The problem is that it won't refresh the widget tree when data is updated.

```
Future<void> getTheUserClasses() async {
    List<ClassData> _classList = List<ClassData>();

    for (String c in user.classes) {
      DocumentSnapshot classsnapshot =
          await Firestore.instance.collection("Classes").document(c).get();

      final data =
          ClassData.fromUserMap(classsnapshot.data, classsnapshot.documentID);

      if (data != null) {
        _classList.add(data);
      }
    }

    notifyListeners();

    classes = _classList;
  }
```

Comment: `_matchData` is a `Stream<Iterable<ClassData>>`.  Does `d.addAll(await _matchData.toList())` do what you want?

Comment: Why don't you query the three documents at once and then Iterate over them instead of making three different queries?
It's possible to query the three documents by using: `myCollection.where(firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), 'in', ["1","2","3"])`